# Tomcat8 start failure with Primefaces JSF App

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tomcat8

I have a JSF2.2 application running fine on Tomcat7. I now have to move it to Tomcat8 and the application is not starting anymore.

The error is:

```
03-Jul-2019 15:41:47.655 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
03-Jul-2019 15:41:47.655 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
03-Jul-2019 15:41:47.655 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
03-Jul-2019 15:41:47.659 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/NPSAdmin] startup failed due to previous errors
03-Jul-2019 15:41:47.662 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
03-Jul-2019 15:41:47.663 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:140)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5474)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have been searching for similar issues and could not solve it. In my tomcat lib I have the servlet-api.jar, but no other jsf related file.
    In my webapp I have:
    jsf-api-2.2.2.jar
    jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar
    primefaces-5.1.jar
    No other jar like javax.faces have been found in the lib directories

We can also see from the logs that primefaces is found and activated:

```
org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener.processEvent Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
```

So my feeling is that it is not a classpatch issue explaining why the Factory was not found.

I searched the tomcat logs, but there is nothing in it

I am running this issue with Tomcat8 on mac osX and on ubuntu

My web.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>NPSAdmin</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>
<context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
    <param-value>npsadmin</param-value>  
</context-param>   
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

    <!-- JNDI DB Connection -->
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/AnonymDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you upgrade / downgrade from an older version of JSF either?

Comment: Get rid of `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` entry in `web.xml` and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. I had also tried to remove `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` entry in `web.xml`.

This did not change.

The reason was simple: a spring component could not start because of a configuration issue. This is where the issue was. The error message was misleading.
I corrected the the configuration and it works.

Please be aware that this error message can be misleading

Comment: Did you encounter additional errors before `Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory` in a log? Would be nice to add this to your post.